# Prog created Buttons from class don't appear - Swift IOS

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

I'm trying to add a number of customClass buttons to my view automatically, based on the size of an array.

Created the class and called the appropriate method in the class, but nothing shows up. Debugging tells me that the method is called/executed as expected (3x).

When I add the function directly to the view controller it does work.

What am I missing here ???

ViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let userArray: [String] = ["One","Two","Three"]

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for item in userArray {
        CustomCheckBox().showNewButton()
    }
  }

.. Other stuff...
}
```

CustomButton class code:

```
{
import UIKit

class CustomCheckBox: UIButton {

let checkedImage: UIImage  = UIImage(named:"chckbox_on")!  
let uncheckedImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "chckbox_off")!  
var newButton: CustomCheckBox!      

..... other functions (isChecked, buttonClicked, ..)

func showNewButton (){
    newButton = CustomCheckBox (type: UIButtonType.Custom)
    newButton.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 45, height: 45)
    newButton.center = CGPoint(x: 40, y: 40)
    newButton.addTarget(newButton, action: #selector(CustomCheckBox.buttonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    newButton.isChecked=false
    self.addSubview(newButton)
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually here `self.addSubview(newButton)` you are adding your `newButton` inside the button you are creating. So you might want to have an argument where you give it a `UIView` to be inserted in or in your `ViewController` you add manually your newly created button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May consider restructuring your code like this

```
class CustomCheckBoxContainer: UIView {
    var newButton: CustomCheckBox!


    func showNewButton (){
        newButton = CustomCheckBox (type: UIButtonType.custom)
        newButton.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 45, height: 45)
        newButton.center = CGPoint(x: 40, y: 40)
        newButton.addTarget(newButton, action: #selector(CustomCheckBox.buttonClicked(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        newButton.isChecked=false
        self.addSubview(newButton)
    }



}

class CustomCheckBox: UIButton {
    let checkedImage: UIImage  = UIImage(named:"chckbox_on")!
    let uncheckedImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "chckbox_off")!

//add here all your button functionality
}
```

and then change your view did load to something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for item in userArray {
        let customCheckBoxContainer = CustomCheckBoxContainer()
        customCheckBoxContainer.showNewButton()
        self.view.addSubview(customCheckBoxContainer)
    }
}
```

Comment: Somehow my button action does no longer work, but at least the checkboxes appear on the screen. That did the trick and I see why it should now. Thnx a 10^6

Answer (score 0):

pass your current View as parameter of your function like this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for item in userArray {
        CustomCheckBox().showNewButton(self.view)
    }
}
```

Modify your custom UIButton function newButton like this

```
func showNewButton (currentView : UIView){
    newButton = CustomCheckBox (type: UIButtonType.Custom)
    newButton.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 45, height: 45)
    newButton.center = CGPoint(x: 40, y: 40)
    newButton.addTarget(newButton, action: #selector(CustomCheckBox.buttonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    newButton.isChecked=false
    currentView.addSubview(newButton)
}
```